# Gedit taking 20 seconds to start up on i3

Tags: gedit, i3-wm

I have installed i3 on my Ubuntu machine. Whenever I try to launch gedit, from command line or dmenu, there is a delay of precisely 20 seconds before it starts. During this time, it consumes no CPU so it is not doing anything. While gedit is running or quitting, there is no lag at all.

Uninstalling it and reinstalling it (using apt) did not help.

Why is gedit doing this and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Instead of having `exec i3` in my `~/.xinitrc`, I replaced it with `dbus-launch --exit-with-session i3`, that way dbus was correctly initialized.